# Is there a DNA analogue to ribozymes?

Tags: dna, rna, enzymes

If not, is it impossible for DNA to have enzymatic activity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not very common, and **not found so far in nature**, but they exist and are called [deoxyribozymes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deoxyribozyme).

Additional information:

Deoxyribozymes are the equivalent of ribozymes in the DNA world and can function as catalysts for different biochemical reactions, such as DNA cleavage. While DNAzymes (short name) were synthesized in a laboratory context (*In-vitro*) and proved to be active, no observations were made of DNA molecules having an enzymatic activity *In-vivo* which is of course not a definitive proof they don't exist in nature.

The latter point is a major difference compared to ribozymes which were proved to be active and functional in living cells.

Comment: How did I miss the analogous name? :P

Comment: @TheObscureQuestion Thought the same when I saw you question :D. By the way excellent question, I actually knew about them because I looked that up recently while asking myself the exact same question.

Comment: Can you at least give a short summary of the Wikipedia article? Dropping a link (and this is more or less it) is usually not appreciated.

Comment: @Karolas I thought about doing that but they are just exactly the same as ribozymes but DNA-based instead of RNA-based. Anyway you are right I will add some more information.